# How can I select an object from an array based on an index in a property of sibling object?

Tags: arrays, json, jq, siblings

I'm trying to process some JSON with `jq` that looks similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Albert"
  },
  {
    "name": "Brian",
    "parentIndex": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Carol",
    "parentIndex": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Dwayne",
    "parentIndex": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Ethel",
    "parentIndex": 3
  },
  {
    "name": "Francis",
    "parentIndex": 3
  }
]
```

I want to find all objects in the list with a particular `name`, e.g. `"Carol"`, then get their indices in the list, and then use those indices to get all the objects in the list which have those objects as their parent, based on their `parentIndex`. So, the above should return Dwayne's object.

I know I can get the indices with this:

```
jq '[.[] | .name == "Carol"] | indices(true)'
```

but not sure how to use the indices to get objects out of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, figured it out while creating a simpler test case for SO. I ended up having to use a variable, which I've never used in `jq` before. If you know a simple way to do it without the variable, I'd be keen to see it.

The above can be solved with:

```
jq '. as $top 
  | .[] 
  | select(
      $top[.parentIndex? | values]
        .name == "Carol"
    )'
```

What it does on each line is:

1. Assign the initial input to `$top`. This is necessary because, at the time we're evaluating whether to `select` an individual object or not, we no longer have access to the whole array without a variable.
2. Split the array into a stream of objects
3. Select objects if...
4. ... the object in the `$top` array at the position of this object's `parentIndex` ...
5. ... has a `name` of `"Carol"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar solution that only examines the first "Carol":

```
(map(.name) | index("Carol")) as $ix
| .[] 
| select( .parentIndex == $ix )
| .name
```

One notable feature of this approach
is that if there is a possibility that there is more than one "Carol"
and if it is desired to handle all these possibilities in the same
way, then one has only to change the first line above to:

```
(map(.name) | indices("Carol"))[] as $ix
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the flow of this better: starting with the string match then pulling out the children. However, I don't think your assertion about swapping in `indices` will work, because then it will be comparing `.parentIndex` to an array of numbers. I couldn't find an easy way to find if a number is in a list with jq.

Comment: You're right: an extra [] is also needed, as shown.